# Normal Random Variable, find probability $a<x<b$

Tags: normal-distribution

Let $X$ be a normal random variable with parameters $\mu = 0.381$ and $\sigma^2 = 0.0312$. 
Compute the following:

**$Pr(0.331 < X < 0.431)$**

Ok so I started off using the formula $Pr({a - \mu \over \sigma} < Z < {a + \mu\over \sigma})$. This yields $Pr(0.79 < Z < 1.05)$. Now I know the formula $Pr(a < x < b) = F(b) - F(a)$. So in this case looking at the table of values for standard normal curve, shouldn't the answer be $0.8531 - 0.7823 = 0.0708$? The correct answer is $0.8926$. Where am I messing up?

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to subtract the mean from each endpoint.  $X= 0.331$ corresponds to $Z = \frac{0.331-0.381}{\sigma}$ which is a negative value, not $+0.79$. Similarly for the upper end $X=0.431$.

If you do those subtractions you find an interval that includes $Z=0$ and the probabioloity you get is much larger than what you arrived at.

Comment: Ah ok. So right now I'm getting Pr(-1.61 < Z < 1.61). This is where I am stuck since (Z < 1.61) - (-1.61 < Z) = 0.9463-0.9463 = 0. How is 0.8926 obtained?

Comment: $P(Z<1.61) = 0.9463$.  But the term you need to subtract is $P(Z<-1.61) = 1-0.9463 = 0.0537$. (Note the less than sign here.)  Then the answer is $0.9463-0.0537 = 0.8926$.